# Auduino: Is the Ground Pin on PWD and Power the same?

Tags: arduino

I got a MEGA 2560 yesterday for christmas. I'm having fun experimenting with it. But looking at the board there was 2 GND (Ground) Pins in the "POWER" section [image]

As you can see, there is 1 GND pin in PWM and 2 of them in POWER, I really don't know the difference between them, I tried searching about it on google but no forum or article came up that explained this.
Can anyone explain?

Comment: Ground is ground, all GND pins are connected together.

Comment: Why did you delete your earlier question that talked about sheds? What does PWD mean (as previously asked on your deleted question)?

Comment: @Andyaka I deleted the last question because my question wasn't clear enough to others. It was not about sheds. It was about the prototype shied.

Comment: What is a "shied" spelt S H I E D - I asked you whether you meant "shed" or "shield" and you don't appear to have taken that on board yet.

Comment: @Andyaka Oh my bad, I meant prototype shield. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference (practically speaking), they are there mostly for convenience.

You can verify this with a multimeter, measure the continuity (resistance) between the different grounds, you'll see they are at the same potential.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Also, is any of the numbers in PWD different or are they just there? I'm trying to use a buzzer with a LCD display. the 8th pin in PWD is being used by the LCD display.

Comment: PWD? You mean PWM? The numbers should match what is on the board.

Comment: Yeah the PWM, I keep saying PWD for some reason.. Anyways thanks!